# Unsupported encoding error message in R when parsing XML file

Tags: xml, r, parsing, encoding

I have a pretty large xml file that seems to be encoded in a format that R does not recognize. This is my code:

```
xmlfile <- xmlParse("file.xml")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error: 1: Unsupported encoding iso-8859-8-i
```

What can I do to change the encoding in order to make the parsing to work?
I must say that this file is pretty big on records so opening it in other softwares like Excel or Notepad for example is not possible.
I cannot use the `iconv` function because this xml file wont even load because of this error..

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you hit up `?xmlParse` you'll see it supports an `encoding` parameter.

Comment: I know but you cannot override the encoding unless the file itself is not encoded at all.